How to replicate OpenSSL RSA encryption in Go?
I'm trying to replicate RSA encryption performed by OpenSSL using the Go programming language. In OpenSSL, I use the following command to encrypt a message with a public key:
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in data.txt -out encrypted_data.bin

I would like to achieve the same behavior in my Go program, but I'm not sure how to configure the encryption to match the result of OpenSSL.

Take a look at https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rsa If you already have Go code as part of your question, you should include it here.

The following code assumes the name of your private key is private.pem and that it starts off with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----:
package main

import (
    "encoding/pem"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    key, err := os.ReadFile("private.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ciphertextBytes, err := os.ReadFile("encrypted_data.bin")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    keyBytes := []byte(key)
    // the second return value are the extra bytes after the PEM
    // has been decoded
    decodedKey, _ := pem.Decode(keyBytes)
    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(decodedKey.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // the first parameter is a customizable random number generator
    plaintextBytes, err := privateKey.Decrypt(nil, ciphertextBytes, &rsa.PKCS1v15DecryptOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    plaintext := string(plaintextBytes[:])

    fmt.Println(plaintext)
}

If your private key starts off with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- you would need to do make the following change:
#
#-----[ FIND ]------------------------------------------
#
    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(decodedKey.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
#
#-----[ REPLACE WITH ]----------------------------------
#
    privateAny, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(decodedKey.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    privateKey := privateAny.(*rsa.PrivateKey)

(my answer is mostly based off of the interoperability examples at https://phpseclib.com/docs/go)
